# version of windows server/IIS supporting classic ASP 2.0

Tags: iis, asp-classic

What is the highest version of Windows Server & IIS that supports classic ASP 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since IIS 5 that is supported, but not installed by default in later versions.

Open Roles and Features on Windows Server and select `ASP` as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows server 2008 and IIS 7.5 support classic ASP.

This link covers the subject of getting classic ASP running on IIS 7.5 fairly comprehensively:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/559/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-70-and-iis-75/